# Calling two functions in my route slim

Tags: php, routes, slim

I am having a issue calling two separate functions in my route. I am using PSR-r autoloading and created my own namespace. 
See code below with two functions.

```
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;
use PHPMailer;

class Mailer {
  public function sendMail($request, $response)
  {
    echo "walking up the hill walking up the hill";
  }
  public function updateDB($request, $response) {
    echo "Sending message sending message";
  }
}
```

I have these two functions and I would like to call them in my route one after the other. How can I accomplish that.

See my route below how would I call the functions?

```
$app->post('/confirm', function($request, $response) {
          //sendMail
          //updateDB
})->setName('usersend');
```

I want to call the sendmail function first and then the update DB after using two separate functions just to keep my code cleaner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load your `Mailer` class into [Slim's Dependency Container](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/concepts/di.html#how-to-use-the-container)
and then inject them in your routes/controllers.
First add your `Mailer` class to the Container

```
$container = $app->getContainer();
$container['Mailer'] = function ($container) {
    return new Mailer();
};
```

And then you can use it in your routes like that:

```
$app->post('/confirm', function($request, $response) {
   $mailer = $this->get('Mailer');
   echo $mailer->sendMail();
   echo $mailer->updateDB();
})->setName('usersend');
```